# SmartPhone with a good SDK on Sprint PCS?

Tags: sdk, smartphone, emulation

For as long as mobile phones have been running third-party applications, I've wanted to try my hand at writing some.

Now that it's coming time to replace my PalmOS-powered Treo 530, I'm looking to acquire a new phone that has a robust platform for third-party development. For contractual reasons, it must work on the Spring PCS network.

Ideally, such a phone would have a well-documented API, a well-supported OS, and an emulator that will run under Windows XP or Fedora Core.

Does anybody know of such a phone?

Comment: I've got high hopes for the new Palm Pre when it comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sprint network, you are probably better off with BlackBerry or Windows Mobile device. Only these two have pretty robust SDKs. If this is not for personal/hobby project work and you intend to develop commercial apps for them then you should go for Sprint 3.3.2 SDK. It works for most sprint handsets including touch screen, Qwerty keypad and flip/slider screen handsets.

As you probably wont be aiming for multiple handset support (like my day job) this will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you liked the Palms, the latest ones run windows mobile, which can run the .NET Compact Framework, which meets your criteria.